# How to change the title form based on a name of action methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have one form and also two action methods my action methods use the same form for Editing and adding
I wanna change form title based on a name of Action methods.
for example, when I click on the add button a movie the title name of form has to be "New Movie".
when I click on the edit button a movie the title name of form has to be "Edit Movie".

```
        public ActionResult New()
    {
        var geners=_context.Genres.ToList();
        var viewModel=new MovieFormViewModel
        {
            Genres=geners
        };
        //_context.Movies.Add(movie);
        return View("New", viewModel);
    }
     public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var movie=_context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id==id);
        if (movie == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        var viewModel=new MovieFormViewModel
        {
            Movie=movie,
            Genres=_context.Genres.ToList()
        };

        return View("New",viewModel);
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Movie movie)
    {
        movie.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        _context.Movies.Add(movie);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("index", "Movies");
    }
```

==================================================

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.MovieFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
}
<h2>New Movie</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Movies"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.Movie.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.ReleaseDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.Genre)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Movie.GenreId, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "Select Genres", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.NumberInStock)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.NumberInStock, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Comment: can you show your view related html ?

Answer (score 0):

my problem is fixed.

```
    public class MovieFormViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            if (Movie != null && Movie.Id != 0)
                return "Edit Movie";
            return "New Movie";
        }
    }
}
```

}